# How to upcast `byref<'t>` to `byref<obj>` in F#?

Tags: reflection, f#, byref

I try to call `JsonConverter<'t>.Read` using reflection

```
static member ConvertRead (readInfo: MethodInfo, converter: JsonConverter, reader: byref<Utf8JsonReader>, typeToConvert: Type, options: JsonSerializerOptions) =
    readInfo.Invoke(converter, [| box reader; box typeToConvert; box options |])
```

and get `FS0412: A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL`

Comment: Looks like answer to the c# question [How to pass an argument by reference using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60830084) does what you want -- specifically using `Utf8JsonReader` as an example.  Is that enough to answer your question?  Do you need help converting it to f#?

Comment: Yes I do need help

Comment: OK, can you show a little more of your current code then?  Specifically how you created `readInfo`, whether you are inside some generic class or method with `'t` as a type parameter, and so on.  I.e. a [mcve] showing where you're stuck.  Thanks!